# Iterate over rows in pandas DataFrame and create a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to create a dictionary using `pandas` DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["p1","p1","p2","p2","p2"],
                   'val': [0, 1, np.nan, 1, 0] })
```

I'd like to create a dictionary with `name` column as `key` and `val` column as `values`. Values will be a list. I am using a `for loop` as the DataFrame is only 100 rows.

```
mydict = dict()
valList = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():

    # create list of values
    ......

    mydict[row['name']] = valList
```

Expected output:

```
{
 'p1': [0, 1],
 'p2': [nan, 1, 0]
}
```

Open to other approaches, but I have a slight preference for using `for loop and iterrows()`.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for explicitness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `groupby` and a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {k:list(v) for k,v in df.groupby('name')['val']}
```

output:

```
{'p1': [0.0, 1.0], 'p2': [nan, 1.0, 0.0]}
```

###### using iterrows (not my favorite option)

*NB. this will be quite slower on large dataframes*

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    d[row['name']].append(row['val'])
    
dict(d)
```